# Get related dictionaries from lists

Tags: python, list

I have two list of different dictionaries (ListA and ListB).

All dictionaries in listA have field "id" and "external_id"
All dictionaries in listB have field "num" and "external_num"

I need to get all pairs of dictionaries where value of `external_id` = `num` and value of `external_num` = `id`.

I can achieve that using this code:

```
for dictA in ListA:
    for dictB in ListB:
        if dictA["id"] == dictB["external_num"] and dictA["external_id"] == dictB["num"]:
```

But I saw many beautiful python expressions, and I guess it is possible to get that result more pythonic style, isn't it?

I something like:

```
res = [A, B for A, B in listA, listB if A['id'] == B['extnum'] and A['ext'] == B['num']]
```

Comment: So did you try that? What happened?

Comment: This way it don't starts, because can't understand what is A,B (before "for"). If I change it to (A, B), script starts but fails with "ValueError: too many values to unpack". I tried a lot of variants, all gives same ValueError

Comment: Can you please complete the code after the `if dictA["id"] == dictB["external_num"] and dictA["external_id"] == dictB["num"]:` ?

Comment: @AbdulFatir, for example, "print(dictA, dictB)"

Comment: do all the dicts contain those keys?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, but they may not have pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close, but you aren't telling Python how you want to connect the two lists to get the pairs of dictionaries `A` and `B`.

If you want to compare all dictionaries in `ListA` to all in `ListB`, you need [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

res = [A, B for A, B in product(ListA, ListB) if ...]
```

Alternatively, if you want pairs at the same indices, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
res = [A, B for A, B in zip(ListA, ListB) if ...]
```

---

If you don't need the whole list building at once, note that you can use [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) to pick the pairs you want:

```
from itertools import ifilter, product

for A, B in ifilter(lambda (A, B): ..., 
                    product(ListA, ListB)):
    # do whatever you want with A and B
```

(if you do this with `zip`, use `itertools.izip` instead to maximise performance).

---

Notes on Python 3.x:

- `zip` and `filter` [no longer return lists](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), therefore `itertools.izip` and `itertools.ifilter` no longer exist (just as `range` has pushed out `xrange`) and you only need `product` from `itertools`; and
- `lambda (A, B):` is [no longer valid syntax](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/); you will need to write the filtering function to take a single tuple argument `lambda t:` and e.g. replace `A` with `t[0]`.

Comment: Yes, that works! After your edition, third variant is what I exactly wanted.

Comment: Beat me to it, with a more in-depth answer, ouch :). `itertools.product` does the nesting `for`-loops for you and looks cleaner in my opinion; I forgot `itertools` had that in there!

Comment: Also, just a note: Python3 doesn't have `ifilter` or `izip`; I'm pretty sure they tried to make everything into a generator, so the built-in `zip` shouldn't give any kind of performance hit. But in Python2, you're absolutely correct to use the generator-generating functions in `itertools`

Comment: @dwanderson yes, it's well worth being familiar with the contents of `itertools`, they come up a lot! And you're correct about 3.x - the built-in `filter` and `zip` take over from the `itertools` versions just as `range` subsumes 2.x's `xrange`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, can you explain exactly how use lambda in your example, because if at "else" I return "None,None", ifilter fails.

Comment: @Arkady why would you include an `else`? Everywhere in my answer, `...` should be replaced by `A['id'] == B['extnum'] and A['ext'] == B['num']`. You don't need explicit `(None, None)`; the non-matching pairs will just be ignored.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I thought lambda has to have if-else statement. This: "for A, B in ifilter(lambda A, B: A['id'] == B['extnum'] and A['ext'] == B['num'], product(listA, listB)):" fails with "TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: @Arkady no, in this case you just want it to return `True` or `False` (i.e. whether or not the pairing should pass the filter). However, you're right that there's an error - the argument will be a two-tuple `(A, B)` - and I have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, for code clarity, I actually would probably go with your first option - I don't think using `for` loops is particularly un-Pythonic, in this case. However, if you want to try using a list comprehension, there are a few things to be aware of:

Each item returned by the list comprehension needs to be just a singular item. Trying to return `A, B` is going to give you a `SyntaxError`. However, you can return either a list or a tuple (or anything else, that is a single object), so something like `res = [(A,B) for...]` would start working.

Another concern is how you're iterating over these lists - from you first snippet of code, it appears you don't make any assumptions about these lists lining up, meaning: you seem to be ok if the 2nd item in `listA` matches the 14th item in `listB`, so long as they match on the appropriate fields. That's perfectly reasonable, but just be aware that means you will need two `for` loops no matter how you try to do it*. And you still need your comparisons. So, as a list comprehension, you might try:

`res = [(A, B) for A in listA for B in listB if A['id']==B['extnum'] and A['extid']==B['num']]`

Then, in `res`, you'll have 0 or more tuples, and each tuple will contain the respective dictionaries you're interested in. To use them:

```
for tup in res:
    A = tup[0]
    B = tup[1]
    #....
```

or more concisely (and Pythonically):

```
for A,B in res:
    #...
```

since Python is smart enough to know that it's yielding an item (the tuple) that has 2 elements, and so it can directly assign them to `A` and `B`.

EDIT:* in retrospect, it isn't completely true that you need two `for`loops, and if your lists are big enough, it may be helpful, performance-wise, to make an intermediate dictionary such as this:

```
# make a dictionary with key=tuple, value=dictionary
interim = {(A['id'], A['extid']): A for A in listA}
for B in listB:
    tup = (B['extnum'], B['num'])  ## order matters! match-up with A
    if tup in interim:
        A = interim[tup]
        print(A, B)
```

and, if the `id`-`extid` pair isnot expected to be unique across all items in listA, then you'd want to look into `collections.defaultdict` with a `list`... but I'm not sure this still fits in the 'more Pythonic' category anymore.

I realize this is likely overkill for the question you asked, but I couldn't let my 'two `for` loops' statement stand, since it's not entirely true.

Comment: Really, I thought I tried this before creating question :-) Thank you!